# Android Studio importing phonegap project: how to open "Import Project" window?

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, import, android-studio

I am following [this instruction](http://code-aspdotnet.blogspot.ca/2014/01/developing-android-application-with.html) to import a Phonegap project to Android Studio, and I am stuck in the importing step:

What the instruction show after clicking "Import Project":

[image]

What I get when clicking "Import Project" in my Android Studio:

[image]

The project structure:

[image]

**What I have tried:**

- Delete `.project` file.
- Delete `build.xml` file.
- Android Studio > File > Open project: not detect as an android project.

Seems like Android Studio is somehow, **automatically** detect the folder as an eclipse project. Anyone have any idea how to "force" Android Studio to open the "Import Project" window like one in the instruction?

Thank you!